# Wrap cstdio print function with C++ variadic template

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, cstdio

I'm writing a lightweight parsing library for embedded systems and try to avoid iostream. What I want to do is write variables to a buffer like vsnprintf() but I don't want to specify the format string, much rather the format string should be infered from the arguments passed to my variadic template wrapper. Here's an example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>


template <typename... Ts>
void cpp_vsnprintf(char* s, size_t n, Ts&&... arg)
{
    std::vsnprintf(s, n, /*how to deduce format string?*/, arg...);
}

int main()
{
    char buf[100];

    cpp_vsnprintf(buf, 100, "hello", 3, '2', 2.4);
    printf(buf);
}
```

I'm looking for a performant solution, maybe the format string could be composed at **compile time**? Or is there maybe an stl function that does exactly what I'm asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with some inspiration from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152042/c11-compile-time-format-string-literal-construction-for-invoking-printf)

```
#include <cstdio>

template<class T> struct format;
template<class T> struct format<T*>       { static constexpr char const * spec = "%p";  };
template<> struct format<int>             { static constexpr char const * spec = "%d";  };
template<> struct format<double>          { static constexpr char const * spec = "%.2f";};
template<> struct format<const char*>     { static constexpr char const * spec = "%s";  };
template<> struct format<char>            { static constexpr char const * spec = "%c";  };
template<> struct format<unsigned long>   { static constexpr char const * spec = "%lu"; };


template <typename... Ts>
class cxpr_string
{
public:
    constexpr cxpr_string() : buf_{}, size_{0}  {
        size_t i=0;
        ( [&]() {
            const size_t max = size(format<Ts>::spec);
            for (int i=0; i < max; ++i) {
                buf_[size_++] = format<Ts>::spec[i];
            }
        }(), ...);
        buf_[size_++] = 0;
    }

    static constexpr size_t size(const char* s)
    {
        size_t i=0;
        for (; *s != 0; ++s) ++i;
        return i;
    }

    template <typename... Is>
    static constexpr size_t calc_size() {
        return (0 + ... + size(format<Is>::spec));
    }

    constexpr const char* get() const {
        return buf_;
    }

    static constexpr cxpr_string<Ts...> ref{};
    static constexpr const char* value = ref.get();
private:
    char buf_[calc_size<Ts...>()+1] = { 0 };
    size_t size_;
};

template <typename... Ts>
auto cpp_vsnprintf(char* s, size_t n, Ts... arg)
{
    return snprintf(s, n, cxpr_string<Ts...>::value, arg...);
}


int main()
{
    char buf[100];
    cpp_vsnprintf(buf, 100, "my R", 2, 'D', 2, '=', 3.5);
    printf(buf);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIABykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIArKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFcSXaYDplCBEzEBNk%2BfoHVtQL1jQTFkTFxibYNTS257SO9Yf1lg5UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQmm27ICgT4qEfYJhoAgje3BJgsyQZPRycGCgr7ACpX%2BzOxC8Dn2/GILCYBCOVjuTxeb0wH12TG%2BfwBQJBBDBJEh0OOvwAVAD9qSySYAOwWQENRzIfZoBhnTCqZLEBkIRoMgRnfaEwHJGqHTYAEUOZjM5gSyXMks21MOFJFMIe8NeUKRxwxBGBoPBeI%2BYXx2DJprNiupZyheHpjOZrPZyE5jp52P5CkF9KOYtlUvQvvlpMpyvlque6veWs2JsxetxUI%2B6GW0XoJPNQapNOtttdLLZHK5drdAqF3vFkrMCQAdGYqAGrEqVXDw4iPtrddj9QnjkWC8RidGzZTLbSbdymU8HX3x7z3Z7hT6JVKFPWMyHYY8Wxq24PY534/iTs60%2BmMyPszPJ/mnYXXXyS17ReWpaYl4HFeuwwjt1GYzqsTiELdm4XhMngwDhOg%2By0AIwBpsOWZ0peeaOs6l73h6pZPr6lbeKuwZNvcdxfhGmDCm4BAAJ6CswbBVvRfwrtGDwomiyAOgA%2BkCYRwcRVIPMkXgpjaIAPKaRYoQynHcUYEDzPsID7NEXhUBxw7BqQgJ4AAXpgalUhowZnmJ6bpLpHHYng3qGaGdynhAhwJFYZgAGwmAkIpyRaJmnqSvZmXp2KQqoC5abp1AHh8vxMdgIAgJhyDzIRvlkuC%2BwQEa%2BxWaKNnUng5H7MFMLis5Fh4PJ6l2SlZrKap7kWAFamWNY7k%2Bk%2BXaHtFVxxQl9VWR5yXVQRVXmsGcmafRVZJbZtynrValOY1LXNR5oW5T5H4PBtVpIRJU6NdiAUQL2N79oCSUjd5l2mgdWXWYN5ppRAxWEj8YBgGWuUldYCgVc1ljZRup7EJgBArAwd0zaaw1EbNZJqoi5FUTRrCYJN%2BwAJIxdto45hOkm3aItDIFxOmYF5lVw%2BaINg8QEMQBoJX7Oj1hheTHUfFj3XxZ68zTUD5KNsRl17ded6nfywCg15vaU8DoPg0pKlqVDgvKsLVOIWOouOtJOo8VFCiTQCIN1vxjaq6SO3a7mU4nc6/IAG5iF4ZFlqbVZSwQcmEWyeDO08oki2h831UTJMBYbxvRj7lhcK1oUIYzBGW2zFlp4RKcbiRiMfMjjCo%2BjXXMXcTBeEQDLJMkHGOwoDB%2B4IVDHQ7gKabdDCadF6ONMAF33Pxl004rdcNwQTcKJpHdSWyXH60YUf0dzzveJgmk95N/NbULsMPJlkJhD7fEC35IcqfVXAaIZA2p8gVc1yPxBGk3tWaRfGiabKLCUfsABKsqaWYTSYAOAimAQAoBGxRRgP2JsKsCRN6XVHs/FSCD%2B4ig4IsWgnAEi8D8BwLQpBUCcDcMtS0yxVhuzMJsHgpACCaAwYsBAmAmBYHiONAA1iATYFI4ESkrBSLgmwEjcISBSCk%2BhOCSF4CwCQl9SB4IIUQjgvAFAgHfnQ/BGDSBwFgEgRkXYGBrHIJQNALw6BxFUbAUxyRzHEAxugEAwAuBmC4IQ5IjgeScAALRnH9KKV8pUuAUn2F4gA6mIWgITQksh1EwEJgp0CGCQmEuIxASBaOOqgMx9A7EOJREYKQcjUDuMyKojgPjzjegCdYIJUSIlRJicQOJXiElJLHCk4gaT2QVPQLQPA0RvR9OiNUywGTrG2PsSAR2t9q6Oy4AATg4tQjiqgXLSGKR4pknAAD0viUCkNqdsgAWkwBhQR8BEEfg41xBgjCTJGTYIZli5KYOwbg%2BhhDiECAMWsfYAA1PAmAADucR0q4EICQcU1D5KbG2RfXgGitB81IEwlhgwOEgDMPMqsUhJCSA0PM4Rzj5kEsAVgjgUj5EfKUSotRtD6GLB0VAGAiAUBZJsTk4xmTsmDCcS4vgdAnjEFURAaIHzohhEaJRTgNDTFsEEAAeQYLQaVmjSBYEhEYcQar8Ag1qI7TAZSCEshqOXdYBCjSYHJQQoZTTiCUQ8FgD5%2BsZHcC0VQAwwAFAAuBQqmiMreD8EECIMQ7ApAyEEIoFQ6g1W6BuYYYwpD9D9OeYsDZpTvEKrMCE3xVSDkUhUVamomyXAMHcJ4VoEh5lBDLX0Uo5RMXiNSOkTZYw/CuObYUBgdaBjxDMNIDomzuijArbkBZtgi2dAYMOqYJRe2NuGD0NtegrRNB7bMPtkhFgKHIWsPQOpMDrB4K8jgOCqVqqUaofwLkvFrP2MAZA9JnE4vSiQ/6Nh9jgsuVC1x%2BwPA8vZFsLg8wEUMsWJwzYsDIPQZg7BiRFLpEgASO/BRvAaW2DpYijJLKIBIGWAQQSBAuXjJyREVGnAr03rvQ%2Bp9ZgcW8EwBckgeBrkRuEETMN0gg3yCUGoD5cbSBAqackANJ6z2oc%2BRwBV5dCP7FQFQfYlHb2SHvY%2B/Yz6uCvvZbYn9IH6WaORai1hlAT2Upkch89ijOC0vUWB0gEGoOwac5B%2BDmx3kXus/ppFJ6zDuas8orzZyDXCsyCASQQA%3D%3D%3D)

Output:

```
my R2D2=3.50
```

You can see that format strings are neatly packed into the binary:

```
        .string "%s%d%c%d%c%.2f"
        .zero   1
        .quad   15
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
void AddFormatSpec(int, std::string& format) {
  format += "%d";
}
void AddFormatSpec(double, std::string& format) {
  format += "%g";
}
// Add overloads to taste.

template <typename... Ts>
void cpp_vsnprintf(char* s, size_t n, Ts&&... arg)
{
    std::string format;
    (AddFormatSpec(arg, format), ...);
    std::snprintf(s, n, format.c_str(), arg...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TYo4xe94n)

Comment: Composing the string at runtime is probably not the best idea. :/

Comment: Yes runtime is the easy way out :)) I'm almost there with the compile time version, but it's quite complicated to avoid the binary bloat etc. Also I want to do it policy based and strip out all the whitespace characters on request.