# User-defined literal to MPL sequence: is this legal?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, constexpr, c++14, user-defined-literals

Being able to convert the string passed to a literal operator into an MPL sequence would be useful, since we would then be able to control code generation based on the contents of the string. Previously, I thought this to be impossible, since the arguments to a constexpr function are not regarded as constant expressions within the function's body. However, I came up with the following workaround that compiles under Clang 3.4.2 and GCC 4.8.2:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct string
{
    const uintmax_t m_str[64];
    const size_t m_length;

    template <class... Ts>
    constexpr string(const Ts... ts) :
    m_str{(uintmax_t)ts...}, m_length{sizeof...(Ts)} {}

    constexpr size_t size() const { return m_length; }
    constexpr size_t length() const { return m_length; }
    constexpr uintmax_t operator[](size_t n) const { return m_str[n]; }
};

template <uintmax_t... Ts> struct sequence {};

constexpr auto
operator"" _tag(const char* str, size_t n)
{
    return n == 0 ? string{} :
           n == 1 ? string{str[0]} :
           n == 2 ? string{str[0], str[1]} :
           n == 3 ? string{str[0], str[1], str[2]} :
           n == 4 ? string{str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3]} :
           n == 5 ? string{str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4]} :
                    string{str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3], str[4], str[5]};
}

int main()
{
    static constexpr auto string = "Hello!"_tag;
    using sequence = sequence<string[0], string[1], string[2], string[3], string[4], string[5]>;
    std::cout << typeid(sequence{}).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
sequence<72ul, 101ul, 108ul, 108ul, 111ul, 33ul>
```

### Question

Does this code invoke undefined behavior, or is it legal?

Comment: It seems correct. Personally, I think that the `MAKE_CHAR_SEQUENCE` from [Aligning static string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22067775/2684539) more scalable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. The conditional operator does not evaluate an operand unless necessary.

You're doing it unnecessarily complicated though. Try to use [string literal operator templates](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-04/msg00998.html) (which are supported by both Clang and GCC). They were originally planned for C++1Y - the proposal got rejected though (no idea why, it was done by Richard Smith and the feature is essential).

And if that isn't portable enough (since it's just a compiler extension for now), you can use binary recursive Macros and an `rtrim` class template, like [VTMPL](https://github.com/Arcoth/VTMPL/blob/master/string.hxx):

```
# define VTMPL_SPLIT_1(s, x) ( x < sizeof(s) ? s[x] : decltype(*s)() )
# define VTMPL_SPLIT_4(s, x) VTMPL_SPLIT_1 (s, x), VTMPL_SPLIT_1 (s, x+1) , VTMPL_SPLIT_1 (s, x+2) , VTMPL_SPLIT_1 (s, x+3)
# define VTMPL_SPLIT_16(s, x) VTMPL_SPLIT_4 (s, x), VTMPL_SPLIT_4 (s, x+4) , VTMPL_SPLIT_4 (s, x+8) , VTMPL_SPLIT_4 (s, x+12)
# define VTMPL_SPLIT_64(s, x) VTMPL_SPLIT_16 (s, x), VTMPL_SPLIT_16 (s, x+16) , VTMPL_SPLIT_16 (s, x+32) , VTMPL_SPLIT_16 (s, x+48)
# define VTMPL_SPLIT_256(s, x) VTMPL_SPLIT_64 (s, x), VTMPL_SPLIT_64 (s, x+64) , VTMPL_SPLIT_64 (s, x+128), VTMPL_SPLIT_64 (s, x+194)
# define VTMPL_SPLIT_1024(s, x) VTMPL_SPLIT_256(s, x), VTMPL_SPLIT_256(s, x+256), VTMPL_SPLIT_256(s, x+512), VTMPL_SPLIT_256(s, x+768)

# define VTMPL_STRING_IMPL(str, n) vtmpl::rtrim<vtmpl::string<VTMPL_SPLIT_##n(str, 0)>>::type

# define VTMPL_STRING(str) VTMPL_STRING_IMPL(str, 64)
# define VTMPL_STRING_256(str) VTMPL_STRING_IMPL(str, 256)
# define VTMPL_STRING_1024(str) VTMPL_STRING_IMPL(str, 1024)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea that such an extension was supported. I prefer the syntax using the literal operator, so I'm glad that I don't have to jump through hoops in order to use it to create strings during compile time.