# Simplest way to combine two strings at compile time with C++11

Tags: c++

I'm trying to concatenate two compile time strings:

```
constexpr const char* getString1() { return "abababa"; };
constexpr const char* getString2() { return "lalalal"; };
constexpr const char* getString3() { return getString1() + getString2(); }; //wont compile
```

Is there a modern, simple way to do this in C++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34590241/560648

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708497/constexpr-to-concatenate-two-or-more-char-strings

Comment: `#define STRING1 "abababa"` and `#define STRING2 "lalalalal"`, then `return STRING1;`, `return STRING2;` and finally `return STRING1 STRING2;`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ugh, Macros. But it does seem to work!

Comment: "Urg, Macros" - Nothing wrong with macros ... as long as you use them for what they were made for.

Comment: When you consider all the alternatives, macros seem like a lowly option. They are more for C than C++.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Not when there are no alternatives.

Comment: @GillBates I agree with you on that,

Comment: After you decay them to `const char *` there is no way for sure. But even without it it does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Given the insistence on a solution involving appending results of `constexpr` functions, this question has no possible answer, other than "it cannot be done".

Answer (score 2):

**This is a `C++17` solution using `std::apply`.**

**NOTE: my usage of `auto` and `requires` pushes this into `C++20`.**

This is actually possible by leveraging the fact that `std::apply` is `constexpr` meaning that you can access and tuple-type, including arrays, in terms of their underlying parameter pack:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

//helper function:
//create array without the last element provided
//used to remove '\0' in concat
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<const char, N> trim(
    auto head, auto... chars
) requires (sizeof...(chars) == N) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(chars) == 0) {
        return std::array<const char, 0>{}; //ignore last element
    } else {
        return std::apply([&head](auto... trim_chars){
            return std::array<const char, N>{head, trim_chars...}; //recurse
        }, trim<N - 1>(chars...));
    }
}

//concatonate 2 arrays by converting them into param backs using std::apply
//this works because std::apply is a constexpr function
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t M>
constexpr std::array<const char, N + M + 1> concat(
    const std::array<const char, N + 1>& n,
    const std::array<const char, M + 1>& m
) {
    std::array<const char, N> trim_n = std::apply([](auto... args){return trim<N>(args...);}, n);
    return std::apply([&](auto... n_chars){
        return std::apply([&](auto... m_chars){
            return std::array<const char, N + M + 1>{n_chars..., m_chars...};
        }, m);
    }, trim_n);
}

//example strings
constexpr std::array<const char, 4> x{"abc"};
constexpr std::array<const char, 4> y{"def"};
constexpr std::array<const char, 7> z = concat<3, 3>(x, y);

int main() {

    std::cout << &x[0] << " + " << &y[0] << " = " << &z[0];

}
```

This outputs:

```
abc + def = abcdef
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a modern, simple way to do this in C++?

The final answer is:

There is no way to do this actually at compile time using `constexpr` functions.

```
 return getString1() + getString2();
```

would try to add two pointers, which makes no sense for the compiler.

Any other attempts would require to inspect the actual character literals for concatenation (e.g. something like `strcat()`) which cannot be done at compile time.

The available alternatives are to use macros as pointed out in comments.

---

<sub>Maybe someone is able to do some black voodoo template magic, but I doubt it's worth the efforts anyway.</sub>

Comment: I heard Jeff Atwood likes Black voodoo's. Anyway, even with that I doubt pointer concat is available.

Comment: @GillBates I doubt so also. But I've seen amazing things like working with counting templates, deduced arrays, offsetof, etc.

Comment: I don't mind if the concatenation works with macros as long as they take input from the function returns.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: @user5024425 As mentioned, no way. Why is it so important it needs to be done at compile time? Is that a XY problem?

Comment: Here is some [template magic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708497/constexpr-to-concatenate-two-or-more-char-strings) by Yakk to do just that :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Hey, great. That's the kind of what I had in mind. Though, I have doubts it's worth it :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is *definitely* not worth the effort :)