# constexpr length of a string from template parameter

Tags: c++, string, c++11, templates, string-length

I am trying to obtain the length of a string passed as a template argument using C++11. Here is what I have found so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
extern const char HELLO[] = "Hello World!!!";

template<const char _S[]>
constexpr size_t len1() { return sizeof(_S); }

template<const char _S[]>
constexpr size_t len2() { return std::strlen(_S); }

template<const char _S[], std::size_t _Sz=sizeof(_S)>
constexpr size_t len3() { return _Sz-1; }

template<unsigned int _N>
constexpr size_t len5(const char(&str)[_N])
{
    return _N-1;
}

int main() {
    enum {
        l1 = len1<HELLO>(),
        // l2 = len2<HELLO>() does not compile
        l3 = len3<HELLO>(),
        l4 = len3<HELLO, sizeof(HELLO)>(),
        l5 = len5(HELLO),
    };
    std::cout << l1 << std::endl;  // outputs 4
    // std::cout << l2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << l3 << std::endl; // outputs 3
    std::cout << l4 << std::endl; // outputs 14
    std::cout << l5 << std::endl; // outputs 14
    return 0;
}
```

I am not very surprised with the results, I understand that the size of the array is lost in the case of len1() and len2(), although the information is present at compile time.

Is there a way to pass the information about the size of the string to the template as well? Something like:

```
template<const char _S[unsigned int _N]>
constexpr size_t len6() { return _N-1; }
```

---

[Edit with context and intent]
I gave up trying to concatenate a set of strings at compile time so I am trying to do it at initialization time. Writing something like `a().b().c().str()` would output `"abc"` while `a().b().str()` would output `"ab"`

Using templates, `a().b()` creates a type of `B` with a parent type `A`. `a().b().c()` creates a type `C` with a parent type `B` which has a parent type `A`, etc.

Given a type `B` with a parent `A`, this is a unique type and it can have it's own static buffer to hold the concatenation (this is why `l5` isn't good for me).  I could then strcpy` each one consecutively in a static buffer. I don't want to use a dynamically allocated buffer because my allocator is not necessarily configured at this point.

The size of that buffer which should be big enough to hold the string associated with `A` and the string associated with `B` is what I am trying to figure out. I can get it to work if I explicitly sizeof() as an extra template parameter (as done with `l4` in the snippet above), but that make the whole code heavy to read and cumbersome to use.

---

[Edit 2] I marked the answer that was most helpful - but Yakk's answer was also good on gcc but except it did not compile with Visual Studio.

My understanding at this point is that we cannot rely on `const char []` with external linkage to provide their size. It may work locally (if the template is compiled in the same unit as the symbol), but it won't work if the `const char[]` is in a header file to be used in multiple places.

So I gave up on trying to extract the length from the const char* template paramter and decided to live with `l4` where the `sizeof()` is also provided to the template arguments.

For those who are curious how the whole thing turned out, I pasted a full working sample on ideone: http://ideone.com/A0JwO8

I can now write `Path<A>::b::c::path()` and get the corresponding `"b.c"` string in a static buffer at initialization.

Comment: What's wrong with your len5? Isn't it exactly what you want?

Comment: You may do something like: `template<typename T, const T& value> struct s; template<typename T, std::size_t N,  const T (&value)[N]> struct s<const T[N], value> s {/*..*/};` (simplified in c++17 with `<auto value>`).

Comment: @SergeyA len5 does give the correct result, but it's not a type. This is a simplification of a more complex problem which requires an actual type.

Comment: What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: What's the problem with allocating the buffer dynamically (and thus not caring about its size at compile time)?

Comment: I updated the question to include more details about the context. I cannot allocate dynamically at initialization time since my allocator is not yet configured. It also helps avoid false positives when looking for memory leaks (i.e. when would I free these buffers?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate string at compile time,
with gnu extension, you may do:

```
template<typename C, C...cs> struct Chars
{
    using str_type = C[1 + sizeof...(cs)];
    static constexpr C str[1 + sizeof...(cs)] = {cs..., 0};

    constexpr operator const str_type&() const { return str; }
};

template<typename C, C...cs> constexpr C Chars<C, cs...>::str[1 + sizeof...(cs)];

// Requires GNU-extension
template <typename C, C...cs>
constexpr Chars<C, cs...> operator""_cs() { return {}; }

template <typename C, C...lhs, C...rhs>
constexpr Chars<C, lhs..., rhs...>
operator+(Chars<C, lhs...>, Chars<C, rhs...>) { return {}; }
```

With usage

```
constexpr auto hi = "Hello"_cs + " world\n"_cs;

std::cout << hi;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f87a04b8b73edf6)

Without gnu extension, you have to use some MACRO to transform literal into char sequence, as I do [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22067775/2684539).

Answer (score 3):

```
constexpr std::size_t length( const char * str ) {
  return (!str||!*str)?0:(1+length(str+1));
}

template<const char * String>
constexpr size_t len() { return length(String); }

extern constexpr const char HELLO[] = "Hello World!!!";
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cca4f36c911283e6).  Recursion wouldn't be needed in C++14.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - while your suggestion would indeed give me room to work with and gcc seems happy with it, visual studio complains that extern constexpr const char HELLO[] has internal linkage.  It has external linkage if I remove the constexpr, but then length() is not constexpr anymore...